# Successful Write doesn't write anything on the file

Tags: c, linux, file, unix, system-calls

First of all sorry if it's a dumb question (and surely it is), but I'm really new to the usage of Syscall in Unix. 
I was trying to write something on a file using "write"; it correctly create the file, but there's nothing written on it, that's the code:

```
int main(void) {
   int fd;
   char *string = "Test";
   if(fd=open("home/user/test.txt", O_WRONLY | O_APPEND | O_CREAT)==-1){
    perror("Open failed");

   }
   printf("%d\n", strlen(string));
   printf("Wrote %d byte on the file", write(fd,string,strlen(string)));
   close(fd);
   return 0;
}
```

Where's my problem ? 
Thank you

Comment: What does write return? What are you getting in your second printf?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem seems to be with this line:

```
fd=open("home/user/test.txt", O_WRONLY | O_APPEND | O_CREAT)==-1
```

The equal comparison operator `==` has higher precedence so it is evaluated first. So instead of assigning the file descriptor number to `fd`, you are assigning the result of the comparison to `fd`.

Fixing this is simple, as you can surround the part before the comparison in parentheses `()`.

Comment: Oh you're right, thank you so much ^^